# Python turtle avoiding animation

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am a newer coder, and I am trying to speed up a drawing using turtle by skipping animation.

I have hidden the turtle and set speed to max, but it is still pretty slow. According to every resource I have seen, I should use `turtle.tracer`, but this no longer exists.

What workarounds can I use?

Comment: Are you sure that `turtle.tracer` no longer exists?  I'm using Python 3.6, and I can use `import turtle ; turtle.tracer()` just fine.  Its documentation even shows up when I do `import turtle ; help(turtle.tracer)` from inside of both `ipython` and the Python REPL.

Comment: `turtle.tracer` still exists. https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer

Comment: [`turtle.speed(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed) should also work: "Attention: speed = 0 means that no animation takes place"

Comment: never mind, thx. Yeah, I kept getting error messages for it not being found, but it ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is indeed to use `turtle.tracer`.  As far as I know, it still exists on the latest Python distributions, so I'm thinking you just need a little push on how to see that it's there.

First, open a Python REPL with either:

```
ipython
```

or

```
python3
```

or

```
python
```

Once you have the REPL up, type:

```
import turtle
help(turtle.tracer)
```

and you will see the documentation for the method you want to use.

You can also see all of `turtle`'s in-Python documentation with:

```
import turtle
help(turtle)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There may not be `Turtle.tracer()` anymore, but there *is* `Screen.tracer()`:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.tracer(0)

while True:
    # Your code
    wn.update()

wn.mainloop()
```